# Is there an Indy server property equivalent to TCustomWinSocket.Data?

Tags: sockets, delphi, indy, indy10

When I work with TServerSocket I can use the property `Data` to store a pointer to a class for example for each client.

Now I will use Indy TIdCmdTCPServer and I'd like to know if there is an equivalent property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is - the `TIdContext.Data` property.  In `TIdCmdTCPServer` events that give you a `TIdCommand` parameter instead of a `TIdContext` parameter, you can access the `TIdContext` object from the `TIdCommand.Context` property. For example:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
    // add whatever you need...
  end;

procedure TForm1.IdCmdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  MyCls: TMyClass;
begin
  MyCls := TMyClass.Create;
  // initialize MyCls as needed...
  AContext.Data := MyCls;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdCmdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Data.Free;
  AContext.Data := nil;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdCmdTCPServer1CommandHandlerCommand(ACommand: TIdCommand);
var
  MyCls: TMyClass;
begin
  MyCls := TMyClass(ACommand.Context.Data);
  // use MyCls as needed...
end;
```

Indy also has another useful feature.  You can derive a custom class from `TIdServerContext`, add whatever you want to it, and then assign it to the server's `ContextClass` property before activating the server.  That way, you can simply typecast any `TIdContext` pointer to your class type when you need to access your custom members.  For example:

```
type
  TMyContext = class(TIdServerContext)
  public
    // add whatever you need...
    constructor Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TIdContextThreadList = nil); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TMyContext.Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TIdContextThreadList = nil);
begin
  inherited;
  //...
end;

destructor TMyContext.Destroy;
begin
  //...
  inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdCmdTCPServer1.ContextsClass := TMyContext;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdCmdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  MyCtx: TMyContext;
begin
  MyCtx := TMyClass(AContext);
  // initialize MyCtx as needed...
end;

procedure TForm1.IdCmdTCPServer1CommandHandlerCommand(ACommand: TIdCommand);
var
  MyCtx: TMyContext;
begin
  MyCtx := TMyClass(ACommand.Context);
  // use MyCtx as needed...
end;
```

This way, you don't need to waste time and memory allocating a separate class per client, when you can use the one that the server already creates for you.

Comment: You said: "You don't need to waste time and memory allocating a separate class per client". It's a new paradigm for me and I didn't understand. I don't want to take advantage of your willingness though I'm kind of doing it right now but... do you have an example?

Comment: I have added some examples.

Comment: Remy, based on the first example, how can I access my class outside an event generated by TIdCmdTCPServer? For example, in TSocketServer I use `SocketServer1.Socket.Connections[number_of_connection].data`. What is the equivalent in TIdCmdTCPServer?

Comment: You really shouldn't be accessing connections outside of the server's events. But if you must: `List := IdCmdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList; try MyCls := TMyClass(TIdContext(List[index]).Data); {use MyCls as needed} finally IdCmdTCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList end;`

Comment: I'm connecting an Android App with a GPRS product through my server. Both App and GPRS are clients. When a client connects, I associate it a class with informations like Index, status, etc. Both connect to the same server. When the app sends a message to the GPRS (using index), my server has to find the client with the appropriated index and send the message off the Android App to it. I used to do in this way with TSocketServer and it works. Do you know a better way?

Comment: What I described is how to do it with Indy. Your App command handler will have to lock the `Contexts` list, loop through the list looking for the appropriate client, send data to it, and then unlock the list.